# How can I make a public "enemyDamage" integer from 1 script, communicate with another script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to coding and am not quite sure how to add context from 1 script to another. For my game so far, I have been Frankensteining code from multiple sources and have head into a dead end. I want my player to take the same amount of damage as stated by enemyDamage in the 'Enemy' script. I'm not too sure what other context to give you, but if you know how you could help me out, that would be awesome!

**Enemy Script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health = 100;
    public int enemyDamage = 10;
    public GameObject deathEffect;

    public void TakeDamage (int damage)
    {
        health -= damage;

        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }
   void Die ()
    {
        Instantiate(deathEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    
}
```

**PlayerHealth Script**

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int maxHealth = 10;
    public int currentHealth;
    public int damage = 1;
    public HealthBar healthBar;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            TakenDamage(1);
        }

        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            PlayerDeath();
        }
    }
    public void TakenDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;

        healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
    }
    void PlayerDeath()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("bean guy");
    }
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D hitInfo)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("We did it boys");
        PlayerHealth player = hitInfo.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
        { 
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("beans");
            TakenDamage(enemyDamage); // I need this to update with enemyDamage 's value
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are multiple ways:

**Make EnemyDamage a Static Variable**

```
public static int enemyDamage = 10;
```

Then you can call it in other scripts with `Enemy.enemyDamage`

Be aware that you can't set static variables in the Inspector.

**Use GetComponent**

```
Enemy enemy = gameObject.GetComponent(typeof(Enemy )) as Enemy;

enemy.enemyDamage
```

**Create a GameManager**

GameManager.CS:

```
#region Singelton
    public static GameManager instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("More than one Instance of Inventory found");
            return;
        }

        instance = this;
    }
#endregion
    
public int enemyDamage = 10;
```

Referencing the GameManager Script:

```
GameManager gm;

void Start()
    {
        gm = GameManager.instance;
    }

//Calling Function in GameManager
gm.EndGame();
// Getting Value from GameManager
gm.enemyDamage();
```

**When to use what?**

- If you want a more short term solution I would use a static variable, not advised with multiple enemies (different enemyDamage Values are now immosible)
- If you have more variables or even functions that need to be accessible from multiple scripts I would advise you to use a Game Manager instead
- You need to get a reference of the Enemy to use GetComponent, but makes it possible to add multiple different enemyDamage Values

Comment: Static is not a solution for component interaction. EneymyDamage is now shared among all enemies and only one version of it exists. It means you cannot have a weak and a strong enemy, they are all inflicting 10 of damage. The question has already been asked numerous times, the answer is GetComponent. Static is not right in this context.

Comment: Edited my post according to you feedback.